# How to handle new collective responsibility

Tags: team

Long story short: my team were each assigned a main focus among our daily/weekly tasks. If we completed early we’d see who else needed help, or what tasks were taking more time.

Now our new team lead has decided that there will just be collective responsibility, which means that I could choose to work on anything, or almost nothing. At least that’s how I see this change. It’s not easily traceable to see who has done what. I’m going to keep working hard but I don’t know if all of my colleagues will.

How should I flag this to the team lead? Or should I say nothing and get on? My concern is that he gets furious when work isn’t complete and now we’re all going to get it as I can’t point to my area of responsibility and show it’s done.

Comment: `which means that I could choose to work on anything, or almost nothing`..no, I don't think so. It means, the team has freedom to choose the work based on their choice, but at the end of the cycle, the work needs to be done. Any work remaining unfinished, will be treated as the teams' downside, rather than finger pointing at individuals.

Comment: Don't you use any tools where tasks are assigned? It should be visible there if you completed 10 tasks and someone else 2.

Comment: `It’s not easily traceable to see who has done what.` - that indicates the process has some issues, it's not the idea, but how it is implemented.

Comment: Have you expressed your concerns to your team lead?

Comment: @dwizum That is exactly his question, if he should or not.

Comment: Thanks, I acknowledge the team lead doesn’t want anyone to stop working, but my feeling is that he is facilitating it. In theory, as long as you look busy when someone is passing you could skip hours of work a day and although the team would get it as a group, you’d get away with it. For example, we had an employee who sat on Facebook on their phone 80% of the time, but everyone knew because their tasks weren’t complete because of the old system rather than the rest of us getting blamed as would happen now.

Comment: And yes, there’s no easy tracker. You’d have to do a lot of work to try to figure out who wasn’t ‘pulling their weight’ if there was such a person. Unless they were super obvious about doing nothing I guess!

Comment: There are many many important reasons why you must know who has done what work. And this goes beyond making sure everyone pulls their weight.

Comment: Important enough that I should reasonably address this with team lead? I feel like this is one of these not-broke don’t-fix situations but there are a few new team members and at least one was actively encouraging this new collective system which added to my concerns.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, and shirking responsibility by the lead. It depends on your colleagues. I've worked in environments where our line manager doesn't assign areas/tasks of work and they've been disastrous to the point where as soon as I started work on a task, everyone else would suddenly also want to do that task, even though collectively we'd agreed that I would do it. Perhaps you could arrange a meeting with your colleagues to just make sure you're not tripping over each other toes? Give it a few weeks, if it doesn't work out, raise with your lead that it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flagging problems is better received when accompanied by solutions. You should definitely bring your concerns to your boss, as at the end of the day it's in his best interest that the team performs.

I would avoid mentioning laziness though, perhaps use the word *impediments* instead. Ie: *John is on Facebook all day* is bad because it's accusatory, but *John is on this task for several days, so he must face a blocker* allows John to save face, smarten up, and put the phone down. Win-win for everyone.

With that in mind, I present you:

### Quick Feedback Cycles

Have a morning stand-up meeting to see what the progress and impediments are. I'm going to highlight a few things from the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-up_meeting), just substitute *scrum* for *daily/weekly focus* (emphasis mine):

> 1. **What did I do yesterday** that helped the development team meet the sprint goal?
> 2. **What will I do today** to help the development team meet the sprint goal?
> 3. **Do I see any impediment** that prevents me or the development team from meeting the sprint goal?

This way everyone can pick their own tasks but no one can hide their laziness for long.

Additionally (and perhaps, crucially) if someone is stuck on a tasks for days at a time, someone else should notice and jump in to help them. Or, if it looks like a task won't be ready by the week's end, the team member should flag it for attention. It works wonders for self-diagnosing problems within the team, and fixing them.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is similar to agile development and as such you can borrow some functions from that development method.

As @rath mentioned, it's a good idea to do daily standups where people can say what they did yesterday, what they will be doing today and if they are blocked from anything.

To answer your questions, you can raise the issue with your manager but you need to be able to provide solutions. One solution would be the daily standups, other would be to communicate with your team members to have a meeting every week perhaps and see where you stand regarding a project. What remains to be done and where you need to focus and divide tasks accordingly.

Lastly, if you want accountability, you can push for implementing a tool like JIRA where tasks are added and assigned to specific people. This way both your team lead and you as team members can go back and see who's done what.

In the end of the day, your team leads want you to police each other. You already know who's slacking and at some point you'll have to confront them as a team to avoid getting heat from your lead.